# Linux Device Drivers possibly missing?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, xubuntu, linux-device-driver

I have just installed Xubuntu. My box runs quite a lot slower than before with Windows 7. I am wondering if I am missing some device drivers. I can use `gnome-device-manager` to list my devices.

In the device list view, I saw several blue question mark on the left side of devices. Based on my Windows experience, the question mark should indicate the device is not properly configured. Is it the same with `gnome-device-manager`?

And most importantly, how could I know for sure whether or not the corresponding device drivers have been installed?

Comment: Yes, you probably are missing some drivers. Specifically, you're probably running an unaccelerated video driver.

Comment: Thanks guys. Could you shed some light on me about how to find which device driver is missing? Thanks.

Comment: It would _really_ help if you edit your question and list your hardware, this allows us to quickly see stuff that is known to be problematic.

Comment: Thanks Tim. But is there a general way instead of a specific way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only know with trying. Like if you get sound, your sound card is ok. If your network card is listed with `sudo ifconfig -a`, then your network card is ok. Your VGA is already ok if you get a picture but 3d accel can be checked with `glxgears`. If you get smooth gears, its ok. (You have to install NVidia / ATI proprietary drivers for this. On Intel the driver comes with 3D already.) That's it I guess.

You can list your hardware with:
`lspci` and `lsusb`

Post the command outputs for the hardware in question. (And tell us the hardware of course.)

Comment: Thanks Shiki. I use the "glxgears -info". and I got this output "GL_RENDERER   = Software Rasterizer
GL_VERSION    = 2.1 Mesa 7.7.1
GL_VENDOR     = Mesa Project
" Though the gear animation seem quite smooth. I am wondering if there's anything wrong with the "Software Rasterizer"? Shouldn't it be "Hardware Rasterizer"? Thanks again.

Comment: The framerate is 93 frames in 5.0 seconds. Is this OK? I am using a ATI Xpress 200 Mobile integrated video card.

Comment: I use the ifconfig -a and I can see my USB wireless adapter listed. But the LED on it kept flashing and I cannot connect to my wireless router.